Unable to Extend Angular Material MatDivider in Custom Wrapper Component
I'm creating a custom wrapper component in Angular to extend Angular Material’s MatDivider, but I’m running into issues where the component styles and properties from MatDivider are not applied correctly. The goal is to abstract MatDivider so users of my library don’t need to import Angular Material directly.
Here’s my current setup:
Custom Wrapper Component (TypeScript):
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDivider } from '@angular/material/divider';

/**
 * `DividerComponent` is a wrapper around Angular Material’s MatDivider.
 * It extends MatDivider and is intended to provide the same functionality
 * 
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'aal-divider',
  standalone: true,
  template: '',
  styleUrls: ['./divider.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DividerComponent extends MatDivider {}

SCSS (divider.component.scss):
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use '../../themes/theming' as *;

@include mat.divider-theme($aal--mat-light-theme);

Problem
When I attempt to use DividerComponent, the intended styles and behavior from MatDivider don’t seem to carry over, even though I’ve extended the class. I see the mat-divider class in the DOM, but it’s not displaying as expected.
Question

Is there a specific limitation in Angular Material that prevents extending components like MatDivider?
Are there other approaches to wrap MatDivider effectively so I can control theming without requiring users to directly import Angular Material?

Any guidance or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The main thing you have to be careful in this approach is that, there is an extra element that wraps your material component, so if there is some CSS selector like mat-list > mat-divider, this will not get applied due to the extra HTML element inserted.

You need to add the MatListModule to the imports array to use the directive.
imports: [MatDividerModule],

You also need to always have component theme mixins inside a wrapper class, I have used :host as the wrapper element.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use '../styles' as *;
:host {
  @include mat.divider-theme($theme);
}

Full Code:
TS:
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatDivider } from '@angular/material/divider';

/**
 * `DividerComponent` is a wrapper around Angular Material’s MatDivider.
 * It extends MatDivider and is intended to provide the same functionality
 *
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'aal-divider',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatDividerModule],
  template: '<mat-divider></mat-divider>',
  styles: [
    `
    @use '@angular/material' as mat;
    @use '../styles' as *;
    :host {
      @include mat.divider-theme($theme);
    }
  `,
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DividerComponent extends MatDivider {}

/**
 * @title Basic divider
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'divider-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'divider-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule, DividerComponent, MatDividerModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DividerOverviewExample {}

HTML:
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
  <aal-divider></aal-divider>
  <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
  <aal-divider></aal-divider>
  <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

<hr />

<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
  <aal-divider></aal-divider>
  <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
  <aal-divider></aal-divider>
  <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you @naren-murali for quick reply, There are couple of problem's here

Try to inset="true" it will add inset twice , because we extend and also use template. inset works on host element.
Try to Apply Vertical=true and you will see it wont effect. I might be missing something here.


@bharathmuppa that is why extending the material component is a bad idea, since you are adding extra DOM element aal-divider between the material components, which messes up angular material calculations.

@bharathmuppa also you do not need to extend MatDivider because you are import the components properties and methods but never using them. If you want to use them you have to copy the source code of matDivider HTML and paste it in your HTML, this will resolve the problems, but think about it, suppose the angular material team changes the code, your code will become out of sync with the main code.
